# Input string was not in a correct format. param.Value = Int32.Parse(shipZipCodeTxt.Text);

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I keep getting this error that input string was not in a correct format. I'm out of ideas why this is happening. I'm trying to write to my database and Zip code is a number. I've tried changing it to a string but that would result in a paramater missing when it was executing the non query.

```
Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 


Line 130:               param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
Line 131:               param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Line 132:               param.Value = Int32.Parse(shipZipCodeTxt.Text);
Line 133:                       
Line 134:               comm.Parameters.Add(param); 

Source File:     Line: 132 

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7472247
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
   ASP.finals_signup_aspx.SubmitForm(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\ectserver\ADELEO10\finals\signup.aspx:132
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Comment: Clean up your error to only the lines that matter, and post the code that is causing this.

Comment: Obviously your user is not reliably vetting their data and ensuring they only enter numbers in the zip code text box.  (especially common for non-american addresses)  Why are *you* not vetting the input string before running it through parsers?

Comment: Typically, you get this error if the string you are passing to `Int32.Parse` is not a valid integer (i.e. it contains characters other than numbers). So does it a/ only contain numbers and b/ have you stripped out any spaces via `.Text.Trim()` for example, or any other special characters? You should also check `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` too to check for when no value is supplied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception is clear, the textbox contains chars that cannot be excluded by the parse routine and that are not convertible to an integer number

You could try instead with

```
int result;
if(Int32.TryParse(shipZipCodeTxt.Text, out result))
    param.Value = result;
else
    Response.Write("Please type a numeric value");
```

At least this approach will avoid the exception.

Another possibility is the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic5) control to your aspx markup

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="shipZipCodeTxt" Type="Integer"
     ErrorMessage="Please type a valid zip code">
     MaximumValue="999999999" MinimumValue="0"
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

and you can also add a RequiredFieldValidator to avoid empty entries

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please type a zip code" 
  ControlToValidate="shipZipCodeTxt" 
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```